# What is the maximum and minimum number of leaf nodes of a binary tree with n nodes?

Tags: binary-tree

As far as I understood, the minimum number of leaf nodes of a n-node binary tree is 1 and the maximum number of leaf nodes is ⌈n/2⌉. Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: you mean a balanced tree, because you can have a binary tree where all branches are left, or right, then you have N nodes and one leaf, if they are balanced then there should be a ratio, not that I know

Comment: No. I am just asking about binary tree in general, not a balanced one.

Comment: You can have a binary tree with no right branch, keep adding all branches to the left, and you will have a binary tree with arbitrary deep and only one leaf.

Comment: You can have a binary search tree for example, you add N, then N-1, then N-2, ..., N-M. You will have a binary tree with no right branch, M nodes and one leaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Leaf node count of a binary tree >= 1 is trivially correct.
- Leaf node count <= ⌈n/2⌉:

Proof:

- For n=1, leaf node count = 1
- For every `<1 left branch & 1 right branch under the same leaf>` you stop a leaf from being so, and create 2 new leafs **(+1 leaf per 2 nodes)**
- For every `<left branch>` or `<right branch>` you create under a leaf, you stop a leaf from being so and create 1 new leaf **(+0 leaf per 1 node)**

Therefore, at maximum **Leaf node count <=** 1 + ((n-1)//2) = **⌈n/2⌉**

Answer (score 0):

To complete, and maybe correct what @Kostas suggested is thinking that what you need to do to get the most leaves is a perfect (full) binary tree, which would make all the non-leaf nodes, nodes with 2 children.

- A - no. of leaves
- C - no. of nodes with two children (ideally, all the other ones)

No matter what, the relationship between these two is

A = C + 1

Now if the number of leaves is maximal, that means all the nodes that are not leaves would have two children, so only in this case it would mean that:
A + C = N (total no. of nodes)

If we turn the equations around we would get: C = N - A =>
A = N - A + 1 => A = (N+1)/2

In the end, the maximum number of leaves (terminal nodes) in a binary tree with N total nodes is **(N+1)/2**

You can even try it out yourself with a program or peace of paper, personally the other answer in here doesn't work when I try to use it, now I may 100% be wrong.